# import woes in python

Tags: python, import, gdal

I'm super new on python and i am just deploying an open source app that was done in python and I'm getting a:

`ImportError: cannot import name DataSource on from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource`

However, this is just fine:

`import django.contrib.gis.gdal`

My current environment setup is:

1. Linux
2. Python 2.7 installed in /opt/python
3. GDAL installed via easy_install like so '/opt/python/bin/easy_install GDAL'
4. Doing #3 looks like it got installed here: '/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/GDAL-1.7.1-py2.7.egg-info'

Could someone guide me here please?

If i could do `import django.contribs.gis.gdal`, how come `DataSource` cannot be imported? I assume `DataSource` is also part of the GDAL library?

Comment: Please indent the code blocks in your question by four spaces. This will make them stand out better. Do the same thing for the error message, and if possible, do provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: Have you defined your datasource path?  
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/gdal/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `python-gdal` installed? It seems that `django.contrib.gis.gdal` *only* exposes the `DataSource` class if it is installed. At least on Ubuntu, installing `python-django` didn't install `python-gdal` by default.

EDIT: as noted in the comments below, you *did* have it installed, but the module responsible for locating it, `django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py` did not find it. If you peek in the source for that module (e.g. http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/branches/gis/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py?rev=8012), there's a `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH` setting that I think you could use to help Django find it.

Comment: I guess? I mentioned I did this:  '/opt/python/bin/easy_install GDAL' did that not install the python gdal? did that just install the main GDAL lib and not python bindings? If so would you tell me how to A. Check if its installed and B. how do i install it? Thanks.

Comment: Durrrr, feeling kind of thick for having missed that. Anyway, `django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py` seems to be the module responsible for locating the GDAL library, so I guess you could try `from django.contrib.gis.gdal import libgdal` in a Python console and see if you can get a sensible error message.

Comment: I get some sensible errors now: >>> from django.contrib.gis.gdal import libgdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 37, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libgdal.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: however i have libgdal.so.1 installed in /usr/local/lib. Should i move that somewhere, or how do i let python know where my libgdal.so.1 is?

Comment: I updated the answer with the stuff we've discussed plus a possible solution.

Comment: Sweet!! Thanks so much likka! Mentioning GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in the libgdal.py saved my day! Thanks so much  for your time!